# Standard function to enumerate all strings of given length over given alphabet

Tags: scala, combinatorics

Suppose, I have an alphabet of `N` symbols and want to enumerate all different strings of length `M` over this alphabet. Does Scala provide any standard library function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892358/expand-a-setsetstring-into-cartesian-product-in-scala):

```
val letters = Seq("a", "b", "c")
val n = 3

Iterable.fill(n)(letters) reduceLeft { (a, b) =>
    for(a<-a;b<-b) yield a+b
}

Seq[java.lang.String] = List(aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc, baa, bab, bac, bba, bbb, bbc, bca, bcb, bcc, caa, cab, cac, cba, cbb, cbc, cca, ccb, ccc)
```

To work with something other than strings:

```
val letters = Seq(1, 2, 3)

Iterable.fill(n)(letters).foldLeft(List(List[Int]())) { (a, b) =>
    for (a<-a;b<-b) yield(b::a)
}
```

The need for the extra type annotation is a little annoying but it will not work without it (unless someone knows another way).

Comment: Can we get rid of the auxiliary list of size `n`?

Comment: @Michael yes using `fill` as 4e6 suggests. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the new version.

Comment: @Owen -- Is there a way to make this work for general sequences (not just strings)?

Comment: @dsg Yes though it is slightly more awkward

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
val alph = List("a", "b", "c")
val n = 3

alph.flatMap(List.fill(alph.size)(_))
    .combinations(n)
    .flatMap(_.permutations).toList
```

**Update**: If you want to get a list of strings in the output, then `alph` should be a string.

```
val alph = "abcd"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when `n` is bigger than the size of `alph`. For example: `alph = List(0, 1)`, `n = 3` yields only 6 sequences, as opposed to the expected `8`.