# Expand Map[String,List[String]] into Cartesian Product in Scala

Tags: list, scala, combinations, cartesian-product, cartesian

I'm looking for a version of [Expand a Set[Set[String]] into Cartesian Product in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892358/expand-a-setsetstring-into-cartesian-product-in-scala/4515071#4515071) based on map type :

I would like to start with :

```
val values = Map(
      "id" -> List("Paul","Joe"),
      "number" -> List("1","2","3"),
      "Type" -> List("A","B","C")
    )
```

And compute :

```
val final = Set(
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "1", "Type" -> "A" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "1", "Type" -> "B" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "1", "Type" -> "C" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "1", "Type" -> "A" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "1", "Type" -> "B" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "1", "Type" -> "C" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "2", "Type" -> "A" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "2", "Type" -> "B" ),
Map("id" -> "Paul", "number" -> "2", "Type" -> "C" ),
....
Map("id" -> "Joe", "number" -> "3", "Type" -> "B" ),
Map("id" -> "Joe", "number" -> "3", "Type" -> "C" )
)
```

I try to transform the following code

```
def combine[A](xs: Traversable[Traversable[A]]): Seq[Seq[A]] =
     xs.foldLeft(Seq(Seq.empty[A])){
     (x, y) => for (a <- x.view; b <- y) yield a :+ b }
```

but I have some issue to understand how to construct all the map to add in the big Set()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:
*(but note that for larger maps this would consume a lot of memory, it may be worth looking into generating a **LazyList** instead)*

```scala
def cartesianProductMap[A, B](data: Map[A, List[B]]): List[Map[A, B]] =
  data.foldLeft(Map.empty[A, B] :: Nil) {
    case (acc, (key, values)) =>
      values.flatMap { b =>
        acc.map(_ + (key -> b))
      }
  }
```

---

*Code running in [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/aCXZn2xMSO6ZF5N6N0rZtw/8)*.

---

BTW, if you use **cats** you could just do: `values.to(SortedMap).sequence`